# Apache 2.2.27 Crashes with CPU at 100%

Tags: apache-2.2, php

We have a processor intensive web portal that can easily reach high CPU usage, when this happens the Apache (2.2.27) server crashes, before when using Apache 2.2.25 (with OpenSSL 0.9.8y) the server did not crash. The error logs below don't make it easy for me to diagnose the exact cause of the problem and I'm hoping that someone could point me in the right direction? Thanks

- Windows Server 2003 R2 32-bit PAE enabled
- Apache 2.2.27 (OpenSSL 1.0.1g)
- PHP 5.3.28
- 16GB RAM
- 3.33GHz Processor (4 cores total)

First Apache Error Log

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
[Fri Apr 11 15:47:24 2014] [warn] Server ran out of threads to serve requests. Consider raising the ThreadsPerChild setting
[Fri Apr 11 15:47:25 2014] [crit] Parent: child process exited with status 3 -- Aborting.
```

Apache Error Log after increasing the Threads to 1500

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
[Mon Apr 14 09:20:41 2014] [crit] Parent: child process exited with status 3 -- Aborting.
```

Event Viewer

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   Application Error
Event ID:   1000
Description:
Faulting application httpd.exe, version 2.2.27.0, faulting module msvcr90.dll, version 9.0.21022.8, fault address 0x0005bb47.
```

httpd.conf

```
ServerRoot "C:/Apache2"

Listen 80

ThreadsPerChild 1500

LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule php5_module "C:\PHP\php5apache2_2.dll"

<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
    <IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
        User daemon
        Group daemon
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin postmaster@localdomain.local
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2/htdocs/localhost"

NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@localdomain.local
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2/htdocs/localhost"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@portal-alpha.com
    ServerName www.portal-alpha.com
    ServerAlias portal-alpha.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2/htdocs/portal-alpha.com"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@portal-beta.com
    ServerName www.portal-beta.com
    ServerAlias portal-beta.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2/htdocs/portal-beta.com"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.0.2:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@ssl-portal.com
    ServerName sslportal.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2/htdocs/sslportal.com"
</VirtualHost>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/Apache2/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "C:/Apache2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>

Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-phpmyadmin.conf

<IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

PHPIniDir "C:\PHP\"
```

httpd-ssl.conf

```
Listen 443

AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl
#SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:C:/Apache2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLMutex default

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2/htdocs/localhost"
    ServerName localhost:443
    ServerAdmin postmaster@localdomain.local
    ErrorLog "C:/Apache2/logs/error.log"
    TransferLog "C:/Apache2/logs/access.log"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile "C:/Apache2/conf/certificates/localhost/localhost.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Apache2/conf/certificates/localhost/localhost.key"
    #SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/Apache2/conf/certificates/localhost/localhost-ca.crt"
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "C:/Apache2/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    CustomLog "C:/Apache2/logs/ssl_request.log" \
              "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.0.2:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2/htdocs/ssl-portal.com"
    ServerName ssl-portal.com:443
    ServerAdmin postmaster@ssl-portal.com
    ErrorLog "C:/Apache2/logs/error.log"
    TransferLog "C:/Apache2/logs/access.log"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile "C:/Apache2/conf/certificates/ssl-portal.com.com/ssl-portal.com.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Apache2/conf/certificates/ssl-portal.com/ssl-portal.com.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/Apache2/conf/certificates/ssl-portal.com/ssl-portal.com-ca.crt"
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "C:/Apache2/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    CustomLog "C:/Apache2/logs/ssl_request.log" \
              "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

httpd-phpmyadmin.conf

```
AliasMatch ^/phpmyadmin(?:/)?(/.*)?$ "C:/Apache2/phpmyadmin$1"

<Directory "C:/Apache2/phpmyadmin">
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Deny from all

    LanguagePriority en de es fr ja ko pt-br ru
    ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
</Directory>
```

php.ini

```
[PHP]
engine = On
short_open_tag = On
asp_tags = Off
precision = 12
y2k_compliance = On
output_buffering = Off
zlib.output_compression = Off
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func =
serialize_precision = 100
allow_call_time_pass_reference = On
safe_mode = Off
safe_mode_gid = Off
safe_mode_include_dir =
safe_mode_exec_dir =
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars = PHP_
safe_mode_protected_env_vars = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
disable_functions =
disable_classes =
zend.enable_gc = On
expose_php = On
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600
memory_limit = 1024M
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off
html_errors = Off
variables_order = "EGPCS"
request_order = "GP"
register_globals = Off
register_long_arrays = Off
register_argc_argv = On
auto_globals_jit = On
post_max_size = 1024M
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
auto_prepend_file =
auto_append_file =
default_mimetype = "text/html"
doc_root =
user_dir =
enable_dl = On
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
max_file_uploads = 20
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
default_socket_timeout = 600
upload_tmp_dir ="C:\WINDOWS\Temp"
session.save_path ="C:\WINDOWS\Temp"
auto_detect_line_endings = On
log_errors=On
error_log="C:\WINDOWS\temp\php-errors.log"
extension_dir="C:\PHP\ext"

[Date]
date.timezone = "Europe/London"

[filter]

[iconv]

[intl]

[sqlite]
extension=php_sqlite.dll

[sqlite3]

[Pcre]

[Pdo]

[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
pdo_mysql.default_socket=

[Phar]

[Syslog]
define_syslog_variables  = Off

[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
mail.add_x_header = On

[SQL]
sql.safe_mode = Off

[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.max_persistent = -1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1

[Interbase]
ibase.allow_persistent = 1
ibase.max_persistent = -1
ibase.max_links = -1
ibase.timestampformat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
ibase.dateformat = "%Y-%m-%d"
ibase.timeformat = "%H:%M:%S"

[MySQL]
mysql.allow_local_infile = On
mysql.allow_persistent = On
mysql.cache_size = 2000
mysql.max_persistent = -1
mysql.max_links = -1
mysql.default_port =
mysql.default_socket =
mysql.default_host =
mysql.default_user =
mysql.default_password =
mysql.connect_timeout = 60
mysql.trace_mode = Off

[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off

[mysqlnd]
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = Off

[OCI8]

[PostgreSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0

[Sybase-CT]
sybct.allow_persistent = On
sybct.max_persistent = -1
sybct.max_links = -1
sybct.min_server_severity = 10
sybct.min_client_severity = 10

[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0

[browscap]

[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 7200
session.bug_compat_42 = Off
session.bug_compat_warn = Off
session.referer_check =
session.entropy_length = 0
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"

[MSSQL]
mssql.allow_persistent = On
mssql.max_persistent = -1
mssql.max_links = -1
mssql.min_error_severity = 10
mssql.min_message_severity = 10
mssql.compatability_mode = Off
mssql.secure_connection = Off

[Assertion]

[COM]

[mbstring]

[gd]

[exif]

[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output = Off

[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled = 1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir = C:\WINDOWS\Temp\
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl = 86400
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5

[sysvshm]

[ldap]
ldap.max_links = -1

[mcrypt]

[dba]

[xsl]

[PHP_PDF]
extension=libpdf_php.dll
[PHP_SSH2]
extension=php_ssh2.dll
[PHP_UPLOADPROGRESS]
extension=php_uploadprogress.dll
uploadprogress.file.contents_template = C:\WINDOWS\Temp\upload_contents_%s
uploadprogress.file.filename_template = C:\WINDOWS\Temp\upt_%s.txt
uploadprogress.get_contents = 0
[PHP_PTHREADS]
extension=php_pthreads.dll
[PHP_EXCEL]
extension=php_excel.dll
excel.license_name=System Administrator
excel.license_key=
excel.skip_empty=
[PHP_BZ2]
extension=php_bz2.dll
[PHP_CURL]
extension=php_curl.dll
[PHP_GD2]
extension=php_gd2.dll
[PHP_GETTEXT]
extension=php_gettext.dll
[PHP_GMP]
extension=php_gmp.dll
[PHP_IMAP]
extension=php_imap.dll
[PHP_MBSTRING]
extension=php_mbstring.dll
[PHP_MYSQL]
extension=php_mysql.dll
[PHP_MYSQLI]
extension=php_mysqli.dll
[PHP_OPENSSL]
extension=php_openssl.dll
[PHP_PDO_MYSQL]
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
[PHP_PDO_ODBC]
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
[PHP_PDO_SQLITE]
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
[PHP_PGSQL]
extension=php_pgsql.dll
[PHP_SOAP]
extension=php_soap.dll
[PHP_SOCKETS]
extension=php_sockets.dll
[PHP_SQLITE3]
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
[PHP_TIDY]
extension=php_tidy.dll
[PHP_XMLRPC]
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
[PHP_EXIF]
extension=php_exif.dll
```

Comment: Do you have any other Apache modules?  Please list *all* of them.  Also, please list all of your PHP modules.  It looks like you're using the Worker MPM and crashes like this suggest you may have a thread-unsafe module.

Comment: @Ladadadada: I've now listed all of the modules, thanks.